How to access Internet on a proxmox VM guest with one public IP?
I have a proxmox server with one public IP. I configured a DHCP / bastion / router server with alpine linux.
This is the /etc/network/interfaces file in proxmox host. I followed this from proxmox doc:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eno1 inet manual
iface eno2 inet manual
iface eno3 inet manual
iface eno4 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address 152.122.64.9/24
    gateway 152.122.64.1
    bridge-ports eno1
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
    bridge-vlan-aware yes
    bridge-vids 2-4094

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
        address  10.10.10.1
        netmask  255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports none
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0

        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        post-up   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
        post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

I am trying to setup a VM where I have connected both the network devices WAN: vmbr0  and LAN: vmbr1 and work seamlessly.
Initially the LAN wasn't working, but after changing the network device model to intel E1000 fixed it.
I am unable to figure out why the WAN won't work with it. I would really appreciate some help for setting up the network properly so that I can have access to LAN as well as WAN.

What's the default gateway advertised by the DHCP server? Is it 10.10.10.1?

yes, it is 10.10.10.1 I have set this in dnsmasq. if i run ip a and I check it shows 10.10.10.2/24 so that is the server ip.

Did you wrongly configure 10.10.10.1 as the IP of this DHCP server VM? By WAN won't work do you mean other VMs (DHCP clients) or the DHCP server VM?

I don't think so unless I missed it. This is my /etc/dnsmasq.conf https://termbin.com/ye4y (it's at the very bottom)

What really matters is the ip r output from the host(s) of your concern (that is, any host(s) you want to "get WAN working").

this is the output of ip r on one of the Guest OS: http://termbin.com/79gy

I assume the proxmox host itself does not have problem reaching the Internet? And the VMs have no problem reaching the host? Perhaps time to add output of iptables-save and nft list ruleset to your post. (I'm starting to wonder if the single quotes would actually be problematic...)

@TomYan I restarted the host and this somehow fixed the issue. I can now access internet through the VM. I truly appreciate your help! Thank you
